# How does React's render() work under the hood?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm confused with `render()` and `this` in React. We have a `render` method in our class component which is the location of our JSX, so when I use

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
```

and

```
root.render(<Counter/>)
```

in my `index.js` file , I expect while I'm using `<Counter/>`, it retrives the JSX from `render` method but when compile my code, I see it has logged `hello` which is located in `constructor` section of class component.

When I use `<Counter>`, is React creating a instance of my `Counter` class component or is it just receiving the JSX from my `render` method? If it's creating an instance why it is logging `hello` twice, is that mean it is creating two instances?

And even if it is creating an instance, the instance creation process is done at `<Counter/>` stage, I've tested it, no `hello` gets logged before `<Counter/>` and I'm not sure if it is making two instances or not but it has to call `Counter()` twice for logging `hello` twice which I guess one of those `hello` logs refers to `instance` creation which includes `Counter()` but I have no idea for second `hello` log.

```
//counter.jsx

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter  extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "jim";
    this.age = 46;
    console.log("hello");
}

state={
count:9
}

   render() { 
    return (
     <>
     <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
     <button>increment</button>
     </>
    );

    
}
greet(){
    console.log("hey");
}
}

export default Counter ;
```

```
//index.js
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
 import './index.css';
 import App from './App';
 import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
 import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
 import Counter from "./components/counter"

 const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
 root.render(
 <Counter />
 );
```

logging info:[image]

Comment: How would it call the method _without_ constructing an instance of the class?

Comment: so then what's going on with `this`...

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to ask. Maybe start with e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: bro I'm asking about `this` behaviour in react and you're referring me to MDN!!! I know how `this` works in pure js the thing I cant understand is what react is doing under the hood...and I think if you read the whole question it'd be clear for you.@jonrsharpe

Comment: React runs on pure JS. `this` in a React class component works exactly the same as in _any other JS class_. So yes, MDN can be helpful.

Comment: "I know how this works in pure js the thing I cant understand is what react is doing under the hood" @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2):

First JSX is just a syntax that gets transpiled (transformed) by a transpiler (usually Babel) to a function called `createElement` which takes parameters defining the HTMl element to be created.

Note this is not a React "thing" for now. `createElement` is just a JavaScript function that should be defined and accessible in the `.js` file that contains JSX. So that when that file gets transpiled by babel and the JSX gets transformed to `createElement(...)` that `createElement` function should be defined.

So **without using React** if you set up Babel to transpile your `index.js` file which contains `<Counter />` the output (transpiled index.js) will replace `<Counter />` with `createElement('Counter', ...)` leaving the burden of defining the function `createElement` on you.

What React does is that it gives you an implementation of `createElement` (when you import React).
In the library `React.createElement` is already defined and it does all the heavy lifting that comes with React.

[React without JSX documentation](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

So now **with using React**, when your `index.js` file which contains `<Counter />` gets transpiled the output (transpiled `index.js`) will replace `<Counter />` with `createElement('Counter', ...)` defined by the React library (because you imported it: `import react from 'React'`). So `React.createElement('Counter, ....')` will get executed.

As for the `render` function, it marks the root of the React instance app. It is not to be understood, because it is where the library internally constructs all the logic needed for the underlying React elements (states, virtual DOM, etc.)

Comment: `React.createElement(Counter, ...)`, not `React.createElement('Counter', ...)` - the leading uppercase character means it's treated as an identifier, rather than a string as it is for e.g. `<div />`.